# JProgress Bar with Values

Tags: java, swing, text, jlabel, jprogressbar

How can you display text inside a `JProgressBar`?  i.e. "000/100"

```
progPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory. createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
timerBar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
timerBar.setOrientation(JProgressBar.VERTICAL);
timerBarLabel = new JLabel("Play");
timerBarLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
progPanel.add(timerBarLabel);
progPanel.add(timerBar);
```

This is my code for my progress bar.

Comment: You say "text inside the `JProgressBar`", but are you just looking to get your hands on the value, or are you looking to create a string of text that says "000/100"?

Comment: How did who get their text inside what JProgressBar? This sounds like it's referring to another question or answer. Nobody knows which post you're referring to. However, please include a full explanation of the issue here rather than just linking to another post. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted [the documentation for JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) (I'm assuming you are using Java 6), you can use the `getValue()` method to retrieve the progress bar's current value from the `BoundedRangeModel`.

So,

```
int maximum = timerBar.getMaximum();
int value = timerBar.getValue(); // This will be the value from 0 to 100 inclusive
String text = String.format("%d/%d", value, maximum);
```

The above would result in `text` containing the string "x/y", where *x* is the current value of the `JProgressBar` and *y* is the maximum value of the same.

If you want to draw this inside the progress bar, you may be interested in `setString(String s)` and `setStringPainted(boolean b)`,

```
timerBar.setStringPainted(true);
timerBar.setString(text);
```

And since the value of the progress bar will be changing, you will want to update the text each time the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I would think something as simple this should do the job:

```
progressBar.setString("Text Here!");
```

Comment: if this answered your question, please mark it as answered so others will know when they view your question.